# Plone: hiding Add-ons from Site Setup

Tags: plone

I'd like to know if there is any product that can help me to hide an Add-on from the list of available Add-ons in "Site setup". Let me explain why.

I am in the situation of hosting multiple customers Plone sites running on the same Zope instance, each site is using a different Data.fs, and I have made a few packages for each customer customization, something like "Customer A Theme", "Customer B Theme". Now, because they are on the same Zope instance, Customer A can see in its site Add-ons list that "Customer B Theme" is also available, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Hiding products from the Add-ons list would be also useful in some other cases, for example a more skilled customer can have PloneFormGen installed, while regular customers don't.

I don't know if such a product exist and I'm willing to make one, if some of you can point me to the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can hide packages from the list of available add-ons; I know [how to do it using five.grok](http://hvelarde.blogspot.com/2011/12/hiding-uninstall-profiles-using-grok.html), but there should be a direct way also.

Comment: Thanks, your post helped me to hide a package.

Answer (score 4):

In your __ init__.py put somewhere

```
from zope.interface import implements
from Products.CMFQuickInstallerTool.interfaces import INonInstallable

class HiddenProfiles(object):
    """This hides zope2 profiles from the add-ons control panel/ 
    quick installer tool.
    """
    implements(INonInstallable)

    def getNonInstallableProducts(self):
        return ['DOTTED_PACKAGE_PATH']
```

Then in a configure.zcml

```
  <utility
    factory=".HiddenProfiles"
    name="DOTTED_PACKAGE_PATH"
  />
```

And replace *DOTTED_PACKAGE_PATH* with the real name, i.e. *collective.myfancypackage*.

Important: If there is more than one profile registered for one dottedpath the alphabetical first is shown as add-on and the others are surpressed.

It is not possible to exclude a single profile, only all profiles of a package. As a workaround it is possible to make a subpackage i.e. *collective.myfancypackage.hiddenprofile/profiles/default*, register it and put in there all the stuff needed to add a profile. Then exclude the dotted path *collective.myfancypackage.hiddenprofile* while the main profile located at *collective.myfancypackage/profiles/default* is still installable as an addon.